# Edits dropped after app switch

Tags: bug, android-app

To reproduce:
Edit posted answer adding a few lines, but don't submit yet. Switch to another app, like browser say. Switch back. Notice the freshly added paragraph is now gone.

Comment: The tagged duplicate is not a true duplicate. This is a bug that still exists, while that is a feature request that is already implemented (as I understand). The bug only happens when you're editing an existing post or saved draft. It happens both when rotating screen and when switching apps, but it doesn't happen when you do that when you're writing a new post.

Comment: @ADTC The duplicate is really a duplicate. It had been mistakenly recast into a feature request, but that's resolved now. Unlike the bug, which is still there and kicking.